# Get Username from database after login

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I'm trying to login a user first, redirect them to an admin panel and then say something like "Good Morning Tim!".

Now to the problem:
I use a session to login the user and the user then gets redirected to the admin panel, so I need to set a cookie with the username and lateron read the cookie on another site.

Here a bit of the code:

** Login-site PHP **

```
$viewable = true;
require_once( './includes/login.php' );

if( isset( $_POST[/*button*/'login'] ) ) {
    if( !empty( $_POST['user'] ) && !empty( $_POST['password'] ) ){
        login( $_POST['user'], $_POST['password'], $loginsite );
    }
}else if ( isset( $_POST['register'] ) ) {
    if( !empty( $_POST['user'] ) && !empty( $_POST['password'] ) ){
        register( $_POST['Benutzer'], $_POST['Passwort'] );
    }
}
```

** MySQL PHP **
<?php

```
require_once('utils.php');

class Connection {

private const server = 'ip';

private const username = 'user';

private const password = 'pw';

private const logindb = 'database';

private $mysqli;

private $debug;

function __construct( $debug = false )
{
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli( self::server, self::username,self::password, 'database' );
    $this->connect();
    $this->createTableIfNoExists();

    $this->debug = $debug;
}

private function connect(){
    if ( $this->mysqli->connect_error ) die( "That didn't work! Contact us." .$this->mysqli- 
>connect_error );
}

private function createTableIfNoExists() {
    //creates database 
$logindb
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . self::logindb . "(
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
        salt VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );";
    $this->mysqli->query( $sql );
}

//debug
private function debug( $msg ){
    if( $this->debug ){
        debug_to_console( $msg );
    }
}

//testet ob die anmeldung erfolgreich war
public function mysql_checkLogin( $name, $pw ){
    $this->debug( 'Checking Login of ' . $name . ' :: ' . $pw );
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare( "SELECT name, password, salt FROM " . self::logindb . " WHERE 
 name = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "s", $name );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if( $stmt->num_rows === 0 )
    {
        $stmt->close();
        $this->debug( 'Could not login' );
        return false;
    }
    $stmt->bind_result( $uname, $password, $salt );
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    $enc = md5( $pw . $salt );
    $this->debug( 'Testing Hash' );
    $this->debug( 'Salt is ' . $salt );
    $this->debug( 'From Database: ' . $password );
    $this->debug( 'Encrypted    : ' . $enc );
    if( $enc === $password  && $uname === $name ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

And the admin panel:

```
<?php $erg = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT name FROM database");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($erg)){
            $fullname=$row->name;
            $names = explode(" ",$fullname);
            echo $names[0];}
```

Comment: These days there's really no reason to write this functionality yourself, use a framework like laravel etc..

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: You seem to be confusing encryption with hashing. Please research more about security and if possible try to use some kind of framework like Laravel that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a cookie.

admin panel:

```
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = $uname;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/", "domain.de/panel/", 1);


$fullname=$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
$names = explode(" ",$fullname);
echo $names[0];
```

And I implemented

```
password_hash()
```

Thanks to Dharman!